# Zero Error, Zero Pages, TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX

Tags: pdf, miktex, texniccenter

[image]I've been playing around with "define output files", I tried all of them acroviewA19, acroviewR19, also 18, 17 etc.

I cannot seem to get any pdf file. It says zero error, but no output generated. 
When I use dvi-pdf, then pdf is generated, I am going nuts.

Anybody have any idea?

I am using TeXnicCenter, and MiKTeX. 
I uninstalled them both, and re-installed.

Comment: why do you think it has anything to do with the pdf viewer? Show a log-file of a small example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, I am pasting the log file.
couldn't, too long it says

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, here is the link, I pasted on pastebin.
https://pastebin.com/uuaZEAAa

Comment: I also checked the registry, I have AcroviewA19

Comment: Compile once on a command line to get a better error message and a better log-file -- yours stops in the middle.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, here it is.
https://pastebin.com/ZjX488Uj

Comment: you are running latex not pdflatex and so create a dvi.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark.  The log file says that `dvips.def` is being loaded in with the `graphics` package.  Such a request for `dvips` may subvert the implicit assumption that this should go direct to pdf.

Comment: @barbarabeeton, when I remove graphics, latex-pdf produced the output, wow! so, now what should I do? I don't really need graphics, but does that mean I cannot use graphics ever?

Comment: I'm used to the dvi request being explicit in the tex source, as opposed to being built into `graphics`, so now I'm stumped.  (I also don't have a workable tex system available at the moment.)  But perhaps this gives enough of a clue that @UlrikeFischer can take over.  But just to check -- you *did* run pdflatex from the command line?  I don't necessarily assume that "latex-pdf" is the same.

Comment: your first log showed that you used pdflatex (preloaded format=pdflatex), the second used latex. Try again on a command line but use this time `pdflatex file` so that we can see what's wrong there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, my bad. I used pdflatex this time.
https://pastebin.com/wEK4sJVt

Comment: looks ok. Try again in texniccenter - but consider to remove the spaces from the file name, I have no idea if texniccenter can really handle them.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, Thank you, it seems like it is ok now, it created pdf. However, my real file (journal article that I am trying to submit, have the same problem. here is the log file from the command line. no idea here whatsoever!
https://pastebin.com/E0R3fdGn

Comment: a log file that stops in the middle either means that you killed the process (instead of using `x` + `enter`, or that miktex had a problem to install a package on the fly (an well known problem of texniccenter).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, yes! you are right! thank you very much. I changed the repository and removed on the fly option. now I can see which one it does or does not install. Thanks for all the help, much obliged!

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thanks for the help!!!!